# toDoList and problem after search of added items that should be back to previous index place when input is empty

Tags: javascript, sorting

When I add new tasks to my toDoList and then searching for them, and empty a search field, my tasks should be back to the previous place. I added some `if` statement, but my previously searched tasks are not in the right index order and at the end of the list instead - they have still the same index when I call `myArray` in console.

My code is below:

```
const myArray = [];

const addToArray = document.querySelector('form');
const ulTasks = document.querySelector('.ul-tasks');
const ulSearch = document.querySelector('.ul-search');
const taskNumber = document.querySelector('h1 span');
const liElement = document.getElementsByClassName('task');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const search = document.querySelector('form .search');



const renderList = () => {
    ulTasks.textContent = "";
    myArray.forEach((toDoElement, key) => {
        toDoElement.dataset.key = key;
        ulTasks.appendChild(toDoElement);
    })
}

const removeTask = (e) => {
    e.target.parentNode.remove()
    const index = e.target.parentNode.dataset.key;
    myArray.splice(index, 1);
    taskNumber.textContent = liElement.length;
    renderList()
}


const addTask = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const txt = input.value;
    if (input.value === "") return
    const addLi = document.createElement('li');
    addLi.className = 'task'
    addLi.innerHTML = `${txt} <button>Usuń</button>`
    myArray.push(addLi);
    renderList()
    ulTasks.appendChild(addLi);
    input.value = "";
    console.log(myArray);
    taskNumber.textContent = liElement.length;
    addLi.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', removeTask)
}

const searchTask = (e) => {
    const searchText = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    let tasks = [...liElement];
    tasks = tasks.filter(li => 
    li.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(searchText));
    tasks.forEach((li) => ulSearch.appendChild(li))
    if (searchText == "") {
        tasks.forEach((li) => ulTasks.appendChild(li))
    }
}

addToArray.addEventListener('submit', addTask)
search.addEventListener('input', searchTask)
```

I expect my task list in the right order after clearing my search input, but now they are at end of the task list. Before I added the following code

```
if (searchText == "") {
            tasks.forEach((li) => ulTasks.appendChild(li))
        }
```

and clear input search field all items (with those I haven't searched) move to the searched place and the list is "empty".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question. Which "list" has the incorrect order after clearing the search field? And I think you mean "After I added <if statement>
". We're also having to guess at the structure of your html, so it's difficult to visualize what you're seeing.

Comment: You should consider separating the data (the list of tasks) from the presentation (the list of `li` elements). That way you could easily make copies of the data in the original order and just re-render the list of elements to match.